# Create a column with daily number of orders in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to create a new column with the daily orders (the count of OrderNumber for each day). Since I have data coming from multiple sources, I'm using SSIS. My final table should look like this:

```
Date | Product Number | Quantity Sold | Number of Orders (for that date)
```

I've tried using Aggregate, but it's not working because of the other columns. I was thinking about creating a parallel source (the same staging table), on which I would use Aggregate to find the number of daily orders, and then find a way to bring it back to the final table, but there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate transform takes and outputs only columns you select. So, for your case, select **Date**, **Product**, **Quantity** and some column for Order Count - we will return to this later. Specify *Group by* for the first two columns, *Sum* for the third, and *Count* for the forth. At output you will receive four columns with desired result.
Source column for *Count* should represent orders and does not include columns used in the first three functions. If you need to use one of these three columns, create a copy of it with Derived Column transfer. I would not recommend using **(*)** (all columns) for *Count*, since it will count rows with Null values as well.